# How to register PKCS11 library in Google Chrome on Windows?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, smartcard, pkcs#11, chrome-native-messaging, gemalto

How can I register the PKCS11 library in Google Chrome when I use a Gemalto smardcard reader?

Comment: Use any of the available chrome extension or Signer.Digital Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not provide a mechanism to specify a PKCS#11 provider, only Firefox does.

You can do client authentication but only with soft certs or smart cards on Windows via CryptoAPI and minidrivers/csps.

Here is a link on using soft certs: https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a422/how-do-i-set-up-client-authentication-for-google-chrome-on-linux.aspx

Comment: Note: the question title expressly calls for Windows

Comment: Yes, and as my answer says Chrome does not provide a mechanism to specify a PKCS#11 provider, only Firefox does. It also states you can do client authentication but only with soft certs or smart cards on Windows via CryptoAPI and minidrivers/csps.

I provided the link for soft cert as an additional reference for others.

Comment: I try to install chrome token signing in my browser, the installation succeed but the problem that the extension return an empty cmd window   native app .exe . Do you have any idea how can I do this
I am using Win 10 x64 with Chrome 58, and chrome-token-signing 1.0.2,smardCard Reader  : gemalto

Comment: I assume you are referring to the Estonian National ID plug-in? I don't have enough experience with it to know how to diagnose it. That said it only would let you use it with sites that have integrated that plug-in.